# button spacing and margin when using bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I am creating a modal dialog in a django template using bootstrap and jquery. The dialog is created as follows:

```
<div id="dialog" class="modal" title="Edit" style="display:none">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Review Uploaded Image</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body"></div>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="test-event">Test</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="test-event2">Test2</a>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" id="save-event">Save</a>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This creates a dialog which looks like the following image (the dialog body is filled on an event)

[image]
The problem is that the two `test` buttons are bunched up together and I would like to have the button a few pixels away from the dialog edge and also to increase the spacing between them. Is that possible to do this in the HTMl itself without modifying the CSS?

Second, I thought to move these buttons in the dialog footer as follows but it changed how the dialog looks in a very unexpected way. I love the buttons to the footer as:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="test-event">Test</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="test-event2">Test2</a>  
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" id="save-event">Save</a>

</div>
```

However, this makes the dialog looks as:

[image]

As you can see the footer separator has disappeared and everything has moved just under the rest of the form elements for some reason.

**EDIT**

The insertion of the HTML is done as:

```
function EditDialog(pk) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("pk", pk.toString());
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'populatereviewform' %}",
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
            pk: pk
        },
        success: function(formHtml){
            //place the populated form HTML in the modal body
            $( "#dialog" ).modal({width: 500, height: 500});
            $('.modal-body').html(formHtml);
            $('#dialog').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                window.location.reload();
            })
        },
        dataType: 'html'
        });

        return false;
    }
```

So, I think I ma adding it into the correct place in `$('.modal-body').html(formHtml);`

Comment: It looks fine when I put it into a snippet: http://www.bootply.com/oapRb5DCWG

Comment: @RachelS huh....ok, I will do more tests and report. perhaps it is because the dialog body is filled later that it has this issue...

Comment: Maybe post the entire modal's html?

Comment: @RachelS Updated the question with an edit

Answer (score 0):

Inserting HTML into the modal should not be an issue, however double-check that you are inserting into the correct section.  It looks like the content is inserted into the footer rather than the body.  You might consider giving the modal-body section an ID so that you can reference it more easily.

Comment: Updated the question with edit to show how it is inserted. Seems ok, I thought...

Comment: Could we see the code that builds the "formHtml"? The javascript that inserts the body content looks fine. http://www.bootply.com/mca80npYIk